# How to use specific network connection to active directory to retrieve user info

Tags: .net, active-directory, network-programming

Need an input on how to connect to Active Directory using specific LAN connection

- Domain `Ab`c ->  connection 1
- Domain `xyz` ->  connection 2

I have 2 NIC card which connects to different networks. At this moment we use virtual image when we need to check/reset any account on Active Directory for a specific `xyz`.

I have written a small app which allows me to access AD (`ABC`) which uses connection 1.

On the internet I came across and have gone through Socket Class (`System.Net.Sockets`) / `System.Net.Sockets` Namespace and before do more research/reading...

Can anyone suggest what is the way to bind it to connection 2 using .NET?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need to do is to use the 'Bind' method of Socket, and when you setup the Endpoint, use the IP address of the Adapter you wish to connect with and Port 0.

I'm on my Mac so I can't test this properly but I believe it'd be something like:

```
var endPoint = new IPEndPoint(nicIpAddress, 0);
Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp );
listener.Bind(endPoint);
listener.Connect(...);
```

AFAIK; At the level that .Net deals with the Network, it doesn't care about the Hardware, it just cares that you're connecting to the right network address; so binding to the Card by it's IP address will (hopefully!) ensure that the traffic for that socket uses that Network interface and not the other.